# Is there a way to change text color based on value in vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js

I am trying to add a style class inside one column that coincides with it being greater than or less than a value? The values are how long it takes a server to complete a request. If it is over .1 I want it to bed red and if below I want it to be green.

I've tried to find something on vue's website and elements.

```
<el-table-column label="Duration"  >
        <template slot-scope="scope">
          <span>{{scope.row.response.duration}}</span>
        </template>
      </el-table-column>
```

.079 in green
.12 in red

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean dynamic styling and class assigment.
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Example you have a `value: 10` and if the `value` is over 5 you want the text to be green:

```
<span :class="greentextclass: value > 5">My text</span>
```

Comment: would I define greentextclass somewhere else in the app?

Comment: @noxford1 yes as a class called `greentextclass` or you could do it like in the link i sent you with the `:style` binding but I think its not as clean